# Escape twice special characters using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following string variable defined in bash as `version`

`Uploaded registry/version1.3.1`

I need to escape the `/` twice so that the string looks like:

`registry\\/version1.3.1`

Is there a way to use `sed` to find and replace all `/` to `\\/`?

Comment: How about `version=$(sed 's#/#\\\\&#g' <<< "$version")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One backslash is used to change an argument to text or vice versa.

```
echo 'Uploaded registry/version1.3.1' | sed 's/\//\\\\\//g'
Uploaded registry\\/version1.3.1
```

In this case you need `\\` for one backslash and `\/`for a slash.

Answer (score 0):

**Using `sed`**

You need two backslashes, `\\`, in the RHS (right-hand side) of the `sed` command to replaces with a *single* backslash.

Also, it is a good idea to use a character other than `/` as a regex delimiter to avoid overescaping.

You can thus use

```sh
sed 's,/,\\\\/,g'
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/t1rDNa):

```
echo 'Uploaded registry/version1.3.1' | sed 's,/,\\\\/,g'
# => Uploaded registry\\/version1.3.1
```

**Using string manipulation**

You may also just use string manipulation in Bash:

```sh
s='Uploaded registry/version1.3.1'
echo "${s//\//\\\\\/}"
# => Uploaded registry\\/version1.3.1
```

Here, the backslash needs doubling again, and a single `\` is added to escape `/`s. Note that `"${s//a/b}` means: *replace all occurrences of `a` with `b` in `s` variable*.